# Open New Activity by id on Listview Item Click ??

Tags: android, mysql

I have a list of technician when I select 1 I want to have his profile, how I can have each detail according to id (I work with volley) ??

Answer (score 1):

You could try to pass the object through Intent:

```
//To pass:intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);

// To retrieve object in second Activity
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
```

Before this, you should retrieve information of each technician with a specific query(a simple findById).
It's important that your class implements the interface Serializable in order to serialize the object that you are moving into activities